# Will Nvidia Optimus be supported in 12.04?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

'cause i'm the owner of a acer timeline with a geforce / cuda / optimus GC, and i want use it with linux...