# How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?

Tags: xorg, nvidia-optimus, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Will Nvidia Optimus be supported in 12.04?It will be improvements in nvidia optimus drivers?

Will no longer need bumblebee to activate nvidia graphic card?