# Using on-board graphics + PCI together?

Tags: nvidia, screen, intel, onboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

I would like to know if it is possible in 10.04.4 LTS to have both an Intel on-board graphics and a nvidia card working their own screen. This works perfectly fine on my Windows install. 
How would I go about doing this, step by step?

Here is my lspci if it helps.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P DRAM Controller/Host-Hub    Interface (rev 02)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P Processor to I/O Memory Interface (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X110 PCI Express to PCI bridge (rev 04)
01:02.0 Network controller: RaLink RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
01:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82562EZ 10/100 Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think the easiest way to go about multiple card setups is to generate an xorg.conf with each card individually and tweak 'ServerLayout', 'Device', and 'Screen' sections combining both generated confs.  Rename what you have to so they don't walk all over each other.

Comment: You are assuming that I know how to do any of that. A more detailed step by step instruction would be most appreciated.

Comment: Due to limitations in the X server it's actually quite hard to get this working properly - it's essentially the same problem as hybrid graphics support (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04 ).  You should be able to span your display across both cards, but it's not well tested and  3D won't work.