# Nvidia gt555m and Ubuntu 11.10 drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a laptop with the Nvidia gt555m on it but i want to use its full power not just the on board graphics. I tried installing the driver provided by Nvidia at
 http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.20-driver.html 
no luck, my pc boots to a black screen with white letters. My card does not show up under proprietary drivers either so i can't find a solution. I have formatted my PC three times now in a day to get past the black screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the graphic card has the optimus chip in it, if so you're a bit out of luck

There's [Bumblebee](https://plus.google.com/102207276811032054708/posts) to support nVidia Optimus though

Post your `lspci -vnnn | grep VGA`

You should read this article [How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

If you find that you do have Optimus enabled and want to use it, you can install Bumblebee like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

If you are on Ubuntu 11.04 or older and want newer drivers (recommended) than the ones available in the official repos, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

Note: No need to change $USER, this variable is set to your username.

Reboot or re-login.

If you intend to run 32-bit programs like Wine and using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric or later, install 32-bit libraries with:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
```

Comment: ... "Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee", please properly cite your sources. The latest instructions for Bumblebee will also be available in http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/6969, please link to that answer instead of copying the wiki.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:0dce] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

<br>That is what lspci -vnnn | grep VGA  gives me as output.<br>
As a matter of fact I have optimus, I will try Bublebee and will post what happens. If I get this black screen again, is there any way to revert back to normal or I have to install Ubuntu again?

Thanks for the info!