# Nvidia GeForce GT630M/GT640M/GT650M graphics card support?

Tags: nvidia

Is the Nvidia GeForce GT630M/GT640M/GT650M graphics card supported in Ubuntu 11.10 or Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just made aware that the newer NVIDIA binary driver should support these chips:
http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-ia32-295.59-driver-uk.html

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: I haven't got the hardware but I would be interested in seeing how it works for people with it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the manufacturers provide a BIOS option for using these discrete cards only, it will likely not be supported because of the [Optimus technology](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969). See also [How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/96552/6969)

The current version in Precise is now [295.20](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-current). According to the [supported chips list](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.20/README/supportedchips.html) the GT 630M and GT 650M are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that it is now supported by 290.35 :

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/295.33/README/supportedchips.html

Comment: Yup, that's the 630M.

Comment: Good news, looking forward to people reporting on Linux hybrid graphics compatibility for these cards.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. You need Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.4.3 if you are with a notebook like the ASUS n76 (with Ivy Bridge 3610qm + gt650m).

It works with Bumblebee and the beta driver 302.xx is available via the x-swat ppa (I'm not sure about this).

Bumblebee installs nvidia-current and related software.