# How to change back to xserver-xorg-video-nouveau?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove nVidia driver and go back to Nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12937/remove-nvidia-driver-and-go-back-to-nouveau)

I try to install GT 630M driver--NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.51.run and nvidia-current, but they decrease the resolution.

That means it failed to run the driver just installed, and also stop the beginning one.

How to change back to xserver-xorg-video-nouveau or how to install the correct driver?

I search for two posts but I can't find the answer:

[How to install gt630M driver on ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194441/how-to-install-gt630m-driver-on-ubuntu-12-04/194466#194466)

[Nvidia GeForce GT630M/GT640M/GT650M graphics card support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114047/nvidia-geforce-gt630m-gt640m-gt650m-graphics-card-support)

Thank you~

Comment: If this is a duplicate, where is the question it is duplicating?