# Installing nVidia GeForce GT630M display driver on Dell Vostro 3460 core i5

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nvidia GeForce GT630M/GT640M/GT650M graphics card support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114047/nvidia-geforce-gt630m-gt640m-gt650m-graphics-card-support)

My newly purchased  Dell Vostro 3460 core i5 has nVidia GeForce GT630M graphics card. But I don't have the driver for it and failed to install it. Please help.

Comment: The version of OS is Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: This is a duplicate and as such the bounty on this question has been returned.