# BumbleBee / getting Nvidia 310.19 Drivers to Work | 12.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10, nvidia-optimus

Asus U31JG - A1 Laptop:

-Intel Core i3

-Nvidia 415m / Intel HD Graphics ( Optimus Technology )

---

Hello, I have been trying for about 3 weeks now to get any kind of Nvidia driver to work, and now am determined to get the 310.19 driver to work. I have tried numerous times of which either nothing happened or my interface ( menu bars, the top and left bar on desktop, and the ability to close a window) would disappear. Apparently I'm not making the connection on how to get these to install properly. I have tried numerous other posts and websites and attempted "bumblebee" to no avail. I am wondering if anyone can write a step by step guide of commands  that I need to run in terminal to get this to work. I've had to reinstall 12.10, so if you could walk me through the process of getting the drivers downloaded and installed, I would greatly appreciate it. I barely know what I'm doing, and this is quite a turn off for someone new to Ubuntu, I really want to enjoy it but this is preventing me from committing. Thank you in advance, and I apologize for being so flustered / helpless with this but I have ran out of patience with this.

Comment: Do you have 'Additional Drivers' installed?  You can install Nvidia drivers from there. `sudo apt-get install jockey-kde`

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

I'm not sure if this will help, but I had a lot of trouble getting graphics drivers working in 12.04 on my Optimus machine.

Here is the procedure I eventually used to get it running smoothly: [How do I get a Dell Latitude e6420 working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133608/how-do-i-get-a-dell-latitude-e6420-working)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the comments and it didn't break anything but it says I am using intel Ironlake Mobile. Is this what it should be showing? I think I need the Nvidia GT 415m.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print` and paste what the output is. :)

Comment: `charles@charles-U31Jg:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 9.0

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.  Turned out it was a missing headers issue.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source    
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current   
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current-updates
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I did everything you said and when I logged back in, my interface was missing. The launcher and top "menu" bar

Comment: did you install different environments to replace unity? Like gnome3

Comment: can you open terminal Ctrl+Alt+T   
unity --reset

Comment: @Charles Mynard it appears this is a big problem with a lot of people.  try from terminal (ctrl+alt+t)  sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current-updates    You may have to start from a fresh install if terminal won't open.

Comment: "Error: the reset option is now deprecated"

Comment: I did that following a link someone else commented, now says im using an intel driver, when it previously did not. Do you think it is working? http://askubuntu.com/questions/133608/how-do-i-get-a-dell-latitude-e6420-working

Answer (score -1):

there are two possible methods:

1. Installing the driver from the official Ubuntu repositories ("nvidia-experimental-310") removes bumblebee-nvidia because the package depends on nvidia-current. To avoid this, you need to get the Bumblebee source and repackage the deb with the nvidia-experimental-310 dependency instead of nvidia-current. You may also need to adjust the Primus paths and recompile it.
2. Add a PPA that uses the nvidia 310 drivers as "nvidia-current" not "nvidia-experimental-310". There are some (like this one: https://launchpad.net/~2nv2u/+... ), but I don't recommend using an unofficial PPA for this. The only official PPA with such a package is, as far as I know, the xorg edgers PPA: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-ed... which has "Xorg packages fresh from git" so it's not stable.

Keep in mind that if you add the xorg edgers PPA, do a dist-upgrade, but you'll get many other packages with the driver (you can't just install the nvidia-current package)