# Battery consumption on ubuntu 12.04 installed on Dell XPS L501x

Tags: dell, overheating

I encountered with the problem that Ubuntu 12.04 causes my battery to consume rapidly as compared to windows. Most of the time, fan is running and system heats up. Kindly help me sort out where the problem is?

Comment: Its a general problem with linux systems. The work is going on.. Windows has got this thing right. It manages the battery gracefully as compared to linux systems. Various steps would help you reduce the gap but in the end, windows will always last more than linux on battery.

Comment: @drake01 Please share some proof/article for enlightening your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this model has nvidia optimus enabled. If your system has duel graphics card and optimus enabled you need to turn off the discrete graphics card. Otherwise both are enabled and lead to high temperature, reduce battery.

**Instruction for installing [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org) to turn off  discrete  GPU and enable only when required**

1. Type the following in terminal,

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
   then
   `sudo apt-get update`

If you are on **Ubuntu 11.04 or older** and want newer drivers (recommended) than the ones available in the official repos, run:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

2. To install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

   `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`
3. Run following

   `sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER`
4. Reboot.

---

*If you just want to disable nvidia card, no need to learn followings*

**Usage Instruction :**

To run a program with nvidia card, use `optirun` command prefixed in terminal.
Like to run `glxspheres` with nvidia card type

`optirun glxspheres`

To run firefox type : `optirun firefox &`

*Note: If you intend to run 32-bit programs like Wine and using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric or later, install 32-bit libraries with:
`sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`*

Linked Questions:

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[Can't use nvidia card/driver on optimus notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119449/cant-use-nvidia-card-driver-on-optimus-notebook/119453)