# colord problem & my monitor resolution 640*480 with no other options!

Tags: nvidia, graphics, resolution, inspiron, color-management

I installed NVidia current driver from ubuntu software center then i started to see that my monitor resolution is not fixed!!
so that every time i log in to my machine i have to change the resolution.

but starting from yesterday, all options have been disappeared & i have one option only 640*480.

i have the problem shown in the link here:
https://mooniat.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/colord.png
which i think is the cause of this.
Any help please, thank you in advance.

specifications:
OS: ubuntu 12.04 precise
laptop: Dell inspiron N5110
GPU: nvidia GeForce 525M

Thanks again, yours.

Comment: isn't it optimus enabled laptop? (ie dual grpahics card.)

Comment: Waw! this is a quick reply :D i dunno, but i think yes cuz i have intel & nvidia as GPUs. if so, what that suppose to mean?

Comment: That mean, never install nvidia-current directly. As it nvidia doesn't support optimus in linux. Follow my answer. If everything ok, accept that answer and post problems if not

Comment: @Web-E ahaa, thanks brother for clarification! i'll follow your answer & let you know if anything happen :)

Comment: @Web-E I followed your instructions but unfortunately no thing has changed! the screen resolution is still 640*480 & i don't any options else.

Comment: @Web-E seems that your answer solved the problem with my laptop being heated up! thanks & i'm still looking for a solution to fix the resolution! :D

Comment: remove the xorg.config file and restart. I should create a new config file. `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup`.. In case of any other problem (no GUI) after this, revert back using `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Let me know the result.

Comment: @Web-E thanks dude! you're really helpful. thanks a lot. now my laptop is working better than before. May Allah blesses you & grant your wishes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove current nvidia driver.

`sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current`

**Instruction for installing [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org) to turn off  discrete  GPU and enable only when required**

1. Type the following in terminal,

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

   then

   `sudo apt-get update`
2. To install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

   `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`
3. Run following

   `sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER`
4. Reboot.

---

*If you just want to disable nvidia card, no need to learn followings*

**Usage Instruction :**

To run a program with nvidia card, use `optirun` command prefixed in terminal.
Like to run `glxspheres` with nvidia card type

`optirun glxspheres`

To run firefox type : `optirun firefox &`

*Note: If you intend to run 32-bit programs like Wine and using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric or later, install 32-bit libraries with:
`sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`*

Linked Questions:

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[Can't use nvidia card/driver on optimus notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119449/cant-use-nvidia-card-driver-on-optimus-notebook/119453)