# cpu fan always working and the air is hot

Tags: nvidia, laptop, dell, cpu, fan

My laptop is a Dell N5110, i3, two video cards: Intel HD3000 and Nvidia GT323M.

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.04.

After I login in the system, the **fan starts working non-stop, the fan air is hot and the noise is disturbing.**

What can I do to get the system working like when I am running windows 7, to get it *quiet and cooler?*

Answer (score 5):

This system has nvidia optimus techonology enabled. Nvidia driver doesn't support optimus in linux. So in linux both graphics card are on which lead to **high battery consumption and overheat**.

In optimus tech, the intel graphics is always on. When you use GT323M, images generated by GT323M actully transported through  intel grphics card.

**options available**

Turn off nvidia GT323M and use intel only. Use Nvidia card with special command only when required. `Also never install nvidia-drivers alone.`

**Instruction for installing [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org) to turn off  discrete  GPU and enable only when required**

1. Type the following in terminal,

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

   then

   `sudo apt-get update`
2. To install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

   `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`
3. Run following

   `sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER`
4. Reboot.

---

*If you just want to disable nvidia card, no need to learn followings*

**Usage Instruction :**

To run a program with nvidia card, use `optirun` command prefixed in terminal.
Like to run `glxspheres` with nvidia card type

`optirun glxspheres`

To run firefox type : `optirun firefox &`

*Note: If you intend to run 32-bit programs like Wine and using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric or later, install 32-bit libraries with:*

`sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`

Linked Questions:

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[Can't use nvidia card/driver on optimus notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119449/cant-use-nvidia-card-driver-on-optimus-notebook/119453)

Comment: Everytime  I upgrade this issue comes back. Cant the Ubuntu team fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It could be your graphics card is stressing.

Try using Unity 2D to see if it calms it down a bit.

Comment: Just sharing what helped me when I faced such an issue. Sorry if it's in the wrong place.