# External display not detected on Lenovo T520

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, laptop, display

In Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I installed `nvidia-current-updates` and enabled the discrete NVIDIA card only in BIOS (Optimus completely disabled). Ubuntu uses the nvidia driver but fails to detect an external DELL LCD U2311 connected to the display port. In Windows everything runs smoothly, it's only a SW problem.

In Displays window I can see only a Laptop screen and `Detect Displays` does nothing.

Comment: is your laptop optimus enabled? In optimus you can't use nvidia card only. Optimus disabled means your intel card is working not nvidia.  See this discussion http://askubuntu.com/q/119449/35775

Comment: No. Optimus and NVIDIA vs. Intel are two independent choices. Optimus is disabled, NVIDIA enabled.

Comment: I get the same thing.  James, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @vinnyjames Hi, my only solution is (whenever I use the DELL LCD) to switch to the DISCRETE GRAPHICS CARD (only, no Optimus) in the BIOS setup. Then reboot and everything works well. Of course, it's not a good idea to do that on battery.

Comment: Do you use a dock or is that straight to the mini display port?

Comment: @vinnyjames Directly, to my T520 full-sized display port. Oh... one thing, I maybe installed drivers manually from the NVIDIA site (shell script) and then ran the `nvidia-settings` utility. Don't know exactly but it should work such that. But struggled for couple of days. Now I am on Linux Mint (Ubuntu based distro).

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04. Further OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years. VTC as `not reproducible`.