# High Temperature on an HP DV4-5110tx

Tags: 12.10, overheating

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my hp dv4-5110tx laptop. It has Intel HD 400 and nvidia geforce gt 630m with optimus gpus.My laptop remain cool most of the time when i use windows 7 but when i start using ubuntu, it's temperature increases a lot. Now i am concerned about it. What is the solution for this ? Is this normal ? or do i have to install any driver?

Comment: The Nvidia power usage isn't that well optimized in the Linux driver. Can you try to disable the Nvidia GPU in your BIOS to verify the cause?

Answer (score 1):

If your system has duel graphics card and optimus enabled you need to turn off the discrete graphics card. Otherwise both are enabled and lead to high temperature.

**Instruction for installing [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org) to turn off  discrete  GPU and enable only when required**

[Ubuntu docs link for updated info](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)

1. Type the following in terminal,

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
   then
   `sudo apt-get update`

For more up-to-date nvidia drivers, you need to add another PPA. As of 12.04, this is still necessary for Nvidia GT 6xxM cards. It may be optional for the GT 4xxM and GT 5xxM series on 12.04. When in doubt, just install it. The command is:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
>
> sudo apt-get update

2. To install Bumblebee using the proprietary nvidia driver:

   `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic`
3. Reboot.

---

*If you just want to disable nvidia card, no need to learn followings*

**Usage Instruction :**

To run a program with nvidia card, use `optirun` command prefixed in terminal.
Like to run `glxspheres` with nvidia card type

`optirun glxspheres`

To run firefox type : `optirun firefox &`

*Note: If you intend to run 32-bit programs like Wine and using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric or later, install 32-bit libraries with:
`sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386`*

Linked Questions:

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[Can't use nvidia card/driver on optimus notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119449/cant-use-nvidia-card-driver-on-optimus-notebook/119453)