# Ubuntu 11.10 problem with Nvidia

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I have an acer with a Gforce graphics card. I installed ubuntu 11.10 and it was working properly until I installed Nvidia drivers via additional drivers, I hit `"nvidia-xconfig"` in terminal and then reboot.

At startup `lightdm` fails to start. I changed /etc/X11/xorg.conf file back to default and reboot. It works properly, but with the default Ubuntu driver.

I want to reconfigure Nvidia and use it. Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: does it have nvidia optimus enabled (duel graphics card) ?

Comment: yes, it has duel graphics card

Answer (score 2):

That was a mistake to install nvidia drivers on a optimus enabled system.It won't work.
First you need to uninstall existing nvidia driver.

1. Uninstall nvidia, run following in terminal

   `sudo nvidia-uninstall`
2. Reinstall the Mesa package for GL:

   `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx`
3. When done, reboot with:

   `sudo reboot`

To turnoff nvidia graphics card and use it only when required install **[The Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html)**:

Add the Stable Bumblebee Releases PPA and install Bumblebee using the proprietary NVIDIA driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

If you have 32-bit applications like Wine, and run 11.10 Oneiric or later, you will need extra libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

Allow yourself to use Bumblebee by adding yourself to the 'bumblebee' group. (replace `$USER` by your username)

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

Reboot or re-login to apply the group changes

If you'd like to run a program on the nvidia card now, use the optirun program:

`optirun firefox &`

To test whether it is working, install mesa-utilities by executing `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

- Run `glxgears`, wait for sometimes, you will get frame rate every 5 second and it will be like 50-60 fps. It means it is using intel card.
- run `optirun glxgears` and see the framerates. It will be much higher indicating nvidia card is working.
- Also you can run webgl tests with browsers.

Read more from [bumblebee wiki](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/)

Linked Question:

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96552/how-well-will-nvidia-optimus-cards-be-supported-in-12-04)

Comment: Tnx , I do that. But, how can I see that a program runs on the nvidia card?

Comment: I love you man!! I couldn't resolve this issue since... 10 years at least. :DD Ok not so much but really. I install linux. I can see my nvidia driver. I install updates and it disappears. :S Couldn't get it back EVER. I STILL can't see the driver but I noticed that it uses it. Stuff like video isn't tearing any more. Desktop looks cleaner.. I LOVE YOU!! THANKS!!!!!

Comment: @dariush answer updated.