# How do I get Nvidia GT650M working?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee, gpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I just bought a brand new asus n56vz laptop witch comes with a 3610qm Ivy bridge (+HD4000) cpu and a a Nvidia Kepler GT650M gpu.
So everything seems to work out of the box with ubuntu 12.04 exept that I can't get the nvidia gpu working (and the fn keys, but I'll try to figure this out later :p)...

I tried to install the last unix driver available on nvidia's website and during the installation process, I had a message telling me that here was no generated xorg script for my distribution... I installed it anyway.

After a reboot I now have a 640p resolution that I can't even change on system=>display ...
Plus, nvidia-settings does'nt seems to find any nvidia card on my laptop.

lspci list the gpu card as a compatible controller.

I would also want to install bumblebee, but without a working gpu, that sure can't happens :p

Comment: you will find a solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120857/nvidia-additional-drivers-empty-maximum-resolution-640x480-driver-disappears/123298#123298