# Need help: multiple displays on Ubuntu 12.04 with NVIDIA driver

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, asus

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on my Asus K43SM Laptop with NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M. I am having trouble connecting another monitor (Samsung SMS19A100) as I don't know where to start the configuration. I have read about editing xorg.conf but I am still not familiar with it and it may be very risky. Need help. Thanks.

[EDIT] btw, I am planning to use TwinView, but I still need more details from the experienced. :P

Comment: your laptop is optimus enabled isn't it?

Comment: yep. and for now, I am having a problem on configuring another display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your additional driver tab should not have any drivers available for the graphics card. Even if it is available, please don't install. Its because nvidia linux driver doesn't support optimus.

Please don't install nvidia drivers from nvidia site either. It will cause black screen/ distorted screen or lower graphics resolution.

You should install [bumblebee](http://www.bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu).

Before proceeding installation I would suggest to read the discussions

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/35775)

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/96552/35775)

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ

**For multi moniter setup keep reading**

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the nvidia drivers for your graphics card (use the `Additional Drivers` tool to install them if not) you should have a tool `NVIDIA X Server Settings` in your menu (`nvidia-settings` in the Terminal). This has lots of options, but you should only need the second entry (`X Server Display Configuration`) which has a graphical interface for setting up twin monitors.

Once you have the configuration you want, the `Save to X Configuration File` button (your password will be required) will make this configuration permanent (otherwise you'll be back to a single screen the next time you restart).

Comment: If this answered your question, edgar, please mark chronitis's answer as correct! Thanks.  :-)